# Drawing to a view from a function

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4

I can draw a line by placing the following into a UIView and connecting it to a storyboard View.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef  context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 10, 50);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
CGColorRelease(color);
```

}

However, what I want to do is to draw a line whenever a button is pressed. To do this I assume I need to write some code into an IBAction. My problem is that I cannot simply place the above code into the IBAction as it gives me an error.

```
- (IBAction)draw:(id)sender{
 //Place code here
```

}

My question is, how can I draw a line each time the button is pressed?

How do I connect similar code to draw a different line that will be triggered when I press a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw on a UIView you have to  subclass your UIView

In .h

```
   @MyCustomView : UIView {
    }

    @end
```

in .m

```
@implementation MyCustomView

- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect
{
        CGContextRef  context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
        CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
        CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 10, 50);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
        CGColorRelease(color);
    }
```

In your ViewController

```
-(void)methodCallCustomView{

       } 

- (IBAction)draw:(id)sender{
   [self methodCallCustomView];
    }
```

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work and gave the following error:
<Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0

Comment: @user1209902 i modified my answer, subclass UIView, and call your custom UIView from the ViewController

Answer (score 1):

So you want the drawRect: method to be called when you press a button? If so, send the message setNeedsDisplay to the view that has the drawRect: code.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my description. It's not the drawRect that I want called. I want to call a function that contains similar but different code.